# How to pass HTML label value to PageModel on form submission

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, model-binding

Not sure if it can be done, but how would I assign an HTML label value to a BindProperty.

In my PageModel, I have a List of DateTimes I generate and this list is used in the Razor Page and displayed on rows. (submissionDates is the list)

```
               <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.submissionDates)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Timesheet.TimesheetStart" class="control-label">@item.Date</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Timesheet.TimesheetNotes" class="control-label">Submission Notes</label>
                                    <textarea asp-for="Timesheet.TimesheetNotes" class="form-control" id="NotesTextArea" rows="3"></textarea>
                                </div>                                
                            </td>
                            <td>  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
```

In the OnPost of the PageModel I need the date from the row submitted to add to the Model.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
         { 
             string weekSelected = Request.Form["Timesheet.TimesheetStart"];
             var emptyTimesheet = new Timesheet()
             {
                Submitted = DateTime.Now,
                TimesheetStart = DateTime.Parse(weekSelected),
                TimesheetEnd = TimesheetStart.AddDays(7),
                ColleagueID = UserColleague,
                BranchID = (int)branchFilter
             };

             if ( await TryUpdateModelAsync<Timesheet>(
                 emptyTimesheet,
                 "timesheet",
                  s => s.TimesheetNotes
             ))
             {
                 _context.Timesheets.Add(emptyTimesheet);
                 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                 return RedirectToPage("./Index");
             }

             return Page();
         }
```

I have tried using Model Binding like I have with TimesheetNotes but that was null, the attempt shown above is reading straight from the Form Response and this is also null.

Am I going about this the wrong way or in my scenario is getting that label value not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hidden input,which name is `Timesheet.TimesheetStart`,.net core bind data with name attribute.And you need to set its value with `@item.Date`.Then you need to put form outside `<tr></tr>`,so that when you click the button,it will only post the values of the current row rather than all the rows.

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.submissionDates)
        {

            <form method="post">
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Timesheet.TimesheetStart" class="control-label">@item.Date</label>
                            <input hidden name="Timesheet.TimesheetStart" value=@item.Date>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Timesheet.TimesheetNotes" class="control-label">Submission Notes</label>
                            <textarea asp-for="Timesheet.TimesheetNotes" class="form-control" id="NotesTextArea" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </form>

        }
    </tbody>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only INPUT elements will be available in the `Request.Form`. You can use an HTML Hidden field for each label. With hidden fields, you can do model binding as well.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="Timesheet.TimesheetStart" class="control-label">@item.Date</label>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Timesheet.TimesheetStart" />
</div>
```